# LOOKUP with dropdown list doesn't work for some keys

Tags: google-sheets, lookup, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

(I apologize if this was answered somewhere else so if it was please share with me because I couldn't find anything)

I have two sheets, one with a long two-column list - first column: city, second column: office

I can't give away the details due to my job's privacy concerns but it is just to group certain cities with certain "offices" and I figured the easiest way to do this would just simply type the office name next to the city all the way down so I could use `=lookup()`

I have a dropdown list that references the range of cities on the next sheet (so all values match exactly as it is) and the cell next to it will populate the office name associated in the next column to the city name.

```
=LOOKUP(B2, Sheet2!A2:A, Sheet2!B2:B)
```

B2 being the cell with the dropdown list, Sheet2!A2:A being the list of cities and Sheet2!B2:B being the list of offices

There are no duplicates in the city list, I have removed them. Though currently, there is only one office type I have included on this sheet for now until I get this working.

Some dropdown items display the office name just fine, others (just random ones) display an error. I don't really understand since they're all in the same place.

I made a copy and moved it to my personal drive so you can look at it directly
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TF1bBQdC8ysA30YcGOmB1ojrvQGnfGrznWOrA1vzHZs/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you for any advice, I'm probably missing something simple or there is a better way to do this.

*update: there was really no point in editing this post but thanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lookup is not working because the search range is not sorted.

The [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570?hl=en) for LOOKUP has a note:

> The LOOKUP function will only work properly if data in search_range or
>   search_result_array is sorted. Use VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, or other related
>   functions if data is not sorted.

You can sort the cities in "Sheet 2", or you can use [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) instead since it supports unsorted ranges:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet2!A:B, 2, FALSE)
```

Comment: I did try vlookup and it told me the values couldn't be strings.

Comment: ah, I was missing something. I think it's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use `VLOOKUP` instead of `LOOKUP`

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet2!A2:B, 2, 0)
```

[image: 0]

if you have more cities you can use arrayformula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B, Sheet2!A2:B, 2, 0)))
```

Comment: thank you, I did try vlookup before but I had the wrong syntax